# Display user information via model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have following problem / question. I am working on my Webshop project (Plain PHP + MySQL), and I’ve build so far registration, login, products and so on using MVC Pattern / Model. When the user **logs in**, it’s going to save the **email only** to **session** ( **$_SESSION[ $customerReposutory->getEmail()]**  ), and going to redirect to dashboard. The problem is, I want to display some information (for instance first name, and last name), and to make a Welcome Message for user inside Dashboard.

***I made this function, that is going to look for user that is logged in.***

```
public function userData(string $email)
{
    return $this->customerRepository->getByEmail($email);
}
```

***Afterward its called inside Dashboard Controller:***

```
public function dashboard(): void {
    $this->loginService->accessDashboard();     
      //Get E-Mail from session 
    $getLoginInfo=$_SESSION['login'];   
      //Look for users with particular email 
    $firstName=$this->loginService->userData($getLoginInfo);    
      //Render to View
    $this->render('dashboard', ['firstName'=>$firstName]); }
```

***Repository:***

```
public function getByEmail(string $email)
{
    $tableName = $this->setTableName();
    $className = $this->setClassName();
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE email=:email");
    $statement->execute(['email' => $email]);
    //Customer Model -> id, first name, last name, password, email 
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $className);
    return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
}
```

What I want is, to access information via Model (class) inside View 
**$customer->getFirstName()**  and not as object  **$customer->first name.** 
Right now, **only E-Mail** method is accessible from model: **$customer->getEmail()**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So did you add those getters to the model?

Comment: Yes I did! All the getters and setters are inside model. And like I said, I can only get E-Mail from model smh.

Comment: You would need to try to avoid queries like `SELECT *`, because that is loading all the information related that record, including sensitive information, like a password. Problems: 1. In case of large result-sets, the unnecessary columns will eat a lot of resources, 2. Such queries are reducing application security, because, assuming that somehow the data is dumped out, sensitive information might be leaked out to hackers Alternative: You could select only the columns you need instead of all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the user via

```
    $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE email=:email");
    $statement->execute(['email' => $email]);
```

but you never store it. Get the results, like this:

```
// select a particular user by id
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT <YOUR COLUMNS HERE> FROM `$tableName` WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email]); 
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

As a result, you will have a `$user` variable which will contain all the information you need. So, you will need to instantiate your model `class` and call its setters to set its values based on what you have inside `$user`. Once you have such an instance, you will be able to use it and get its attributes via calling some getters.

Comment: What I did now, I've created another model (NameModel), and the exact same code works fine. But I think it's not that good in practice. Nagyon szepen koszonom a segitsegedet! @Lajos :)

Comment: @dnyprcy nagyon szívesen, további kellemes kódolást! (You are welcome, happy coding!)